# Error In snowplow-elastic sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, snowplow

recently tried upgrading the snowplow r65 to r85 all seems to working fine but the snowplow-elastic sync is throwing the bwlow error.

**[pool-1-thread-1] WARN com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.storage.kinesis.elasticsearch.SnowplowElasticsearchTransformer - Expected 131 fields, received 1 fields. This may be caused by using an outdated version of Snowplow Kinesis Enrich.**

but all my jars are up to date.can anyone help me to identify the problem.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this issue.was having problem with the enricher format.